# UITableView данные не обновляются(reloadData)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Вызываю внутри completionHandler блока, который находится в загрузке экрана.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                          dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {}
```

При завершении загрузки, данные должны бы обновится(отладчик попадает на reloadData), но после reloadData ничего не происходит, в методы

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

повторно не попадаем.
**Важный момент: self.tableView** по умолчанию не знает такого свойства, поэтому я его объявляю свойство(привязывая к TableView в Main.storyboard)

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А delegate и dataSource для self.tableView Вы указали? Если нет, то обязательно надо указывать: `self.tableView.delegate = self; self.tableView.dataSource = self;`

Второй вариант, так как Вы делаете `reloadData` внутри `completionHandler`, Вы должны указать, чтобы обновление было в главном потоке.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: Добавил скриншот, в Main.storyboard указывал самого себя

Comment: Внес изменения в ответ

Comment: dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue() - в корне не верно! Вы пытаетесь запустить синхронную(!) операцию в главном потоке. Произойдет следующее: Главный поток остановится, что бы вызвать синхронную операцию у самого себя. Он никогда не выполнится.